# How do I use the word "stagger" correctly?

Tags: word-usage

Please check the wording below.

1. *After breaking his leg, he **staggered** to his feet again and started again.*
2. *After going broke, he **staggered** to his feet again and started a new business.*

Are they correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, both of your sentences are correct. "Stagger" can be used both in a literal sense (having trouble walking) and in a metaphorical sense (struggling to grow a new business).

Both of your sentences are clear in their meaning, but I think in order to be 100% correct, you need make some tweaks. "Stagger" means most commonly (in my personal experience) "to walk or cause to walk unsteadily as if about to fall". It has [a lot of nuances in its meaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stagger), but for the most part, someone who is staggering is already standing up and walking (though not well).

For that reason, I would be more likely to say:

> After breaking his leg, he **struggled** to his feet and **staggered** home.

Staggering is more what he would do after he managed to get himself standing.

> After going broke, he **struggled** to get back on his feet. He started a new business that **staggered** forward.

n.b.: Be careful in the second sentence: "staggering" can be an adjective, [meaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/staggering) "causing great astonishment, amazement, or dismay; overwhelming". Starting a "staggering new business" probably means that the business is unexpectedly doing very well, not that it is struggling. You want to be sure to include a word like "forward" that shows movement, like the business is going forward on shaky legs.

Comment: No problem - hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Stagger also means *To arrange in a zig-zag pattern*.  For instance:

> He staggered the chairs so no one's view was blocked.

This definition is most likely where we get the usage you were looking for.  (e.g.  walking unsteadily in a zip-zag pattern.)

Comment: The earliest recorded instance of “stagger” meaning “arrange in a zig-zag pattern” is 1856, after hundreds of years of meaning “sway/totter/reel”.

Comment: I remember an old Dennis the Menace comic where his parents were hanging pictures in the stairway (in a zig-zag pattern) and Dennis answered the phone and said his mom couldn't answer because she was helping her dad stagger up the stairs.